# How to convert Kotlin ByteArray to NsData and viceversa

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

Fighting with a Kotlin Multiplatform project I have ended with the problem of needing to work with `NsData` on my iOS platform from the `sharedModule` working with Kotlin Native.

Because of this, I need to transform objectiveC `NsData` to Kotlin `ByteArray` and way back. How can I do this?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**NsData to ByteArray**

```
actual typealias ImageBytes = NSData
actual fun ImageBytes.toByteArray(): ByteArray = ByteArray(this@toByteArray.length.toInt()).apply {
    usePinned {
        memcpy(it.addressOf(0), this@toByteArray.bytes, this@toByteArray.length)
    }
}
```

**ByteArray to NsData**

```
actual fun ByteArray.toImageBytes(): ImageBytes? = memScoped {
    val string = NSString.create(string = this@toImageBytes.decodeToString())
    return string.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
}
```

**ByteArray to NsData different way**

```
actual fun ByteArray.toImageBytes() : ImageBytes = memScoped { 
    NSData.create(bytes = allocArrayOf(this@toImageBytes), 
        length = this@toImageBytes.size.toULong()) 
}
```

Comment: Note option with converting to and then from `NSString` may give you a screwed up result because such conversion adds extra bytes to output, that's why its better to use *only* `allocArrayOf` method

Comment: For anyone looking at this solution, note that there are imports needed. I posted https://gist.github.com/noahsark769/61cfb7a8b7231e2069a9dab94cf74a62 which has the full compiling code I used here

Comment: How can I convert KotlinByteArray to nsdata/nsstring on Swift side after I got it from KMM?

Comment: @stackich I had the same problem – the only way I found was to define a `ByteArray`-to-`NSData` method in Kotlin and call it from Swift. `fun ByteArray.toNSData() = this.usePinned { NSData.create(it.addressOf(0), this.size.convert()) }`