Problem working with image url in iosMain in Kotlin Multiplatform
I try to covert ByteArray to UIImage and after that CIImage to get NSURL from CIImage and upload to Firebase Storage using the url, but I receive null value from the step of getting CIImage from UIImage, do someone encountered with this issue?
I tried to convert ByteArray to NSData and create UIImage from data, it succeed, but after that step I receive null value.
package app.data.imagePicker

import dev.gitlive.firebase.storage.File
import kotlinx.cinterop.BetaInteropApi
import kotlinx.cinterop.ExperimentalForeignApi
import kotlinx.cinterop.addressOf
import kotlinx.cinterop.convert
import kotlinx.cinterop.usePinned
import platform.CoreImage.CIImage
import platform.Foundation.NSData
import platform.Foundation.create
import platform.UIKit.UIImage
    
@OptIn(BetaInteropApi::class, ExperimentalForeignApi::class)
actual fun toFile(image: ByteArray): File? {
    val ciImage = image.toNativeImage()
    if (ciImage?.url() != null) {
        return File(url = ciImage.url()!!)
    } else {
        return null
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalForeignApi::class, BetaInteropApi::class)
fun ByteArray.toNativeImage(): CIImage? = this.usePinned {
    val nsData = NSData.create(bytes = it.addressOf(0), this.size.convert())
    
    return CIImage.imageWithData(nsData)
}


Can you add some code ?

Just added ios part of the code where the problem occures

val ciImage = image.toNativeImage() , here you get ciiimage as nil ?

Please check ByteArray to NSData https://stackoverflow.com/a/58521109/833395

CIImage is not null, but url of the image is null

this is the CIImage.properties log:
{{TIFF}={Orientation=1, ResolutionUnit=2, XResolution=72.0, YResolution=72.0}, {Exif}={PixelYDimension=1536, PixelXDimension=1152}, {JFIF}={DensityUnit=0, YDensity=72, XDensity=72, JFIFVersion=[1, 0, 1]}, ProfileName=sRGB IEC61966-2.1, PixelHeight=1536, DPIWidth=72.0, DPIHeight=72.0, ColorModel=RGB, Depth=8, Orientation=1, PixelWidth=1152}

i think you are creating CIIMage from nsdata. So, it is an object. You need to save this image in file system, like documents directory in iOS. then you cabn find the local url.

how can I do it?

Please search like save the image in documents directory for ios, kotlin multiplatform

https://stackoverflow.com/q/78136270/833395 please check question
